# PHP proc_open not working correctly with John the Ripper

Tags: php, process, exec

I am trying to run John the Ripper from a PHP script. I want to run it and then monitor its output, reacting accordingly. However, things don't work as expected and the results I get are (to my understanding) random. I can imagine that I am missing something.

The problem is that the output stream doesn't produce any output. This is somewhat normal for John -- output is produced when the user types a character using the keyboard. So, I write to the stdin pipe that I have set up. However, that does not lead to john producing output. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
<?php

$descriptorspec = array (
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "w")   // stderr is a file to write to
);

// JOHN is the full path to the john executable
$command = JOHN . " --nolog --config=" . dirname (JOHN) . "/john.conf working/hashes-job-{$_POST['id']} --pot=working/hashes-job-{$_POST['id']}.pot";// --format=raw-md5";
$process = proc_open ($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource ($process)) {
    sleep(5);
    fwrite ($pipes[0], "a\n");
    fflush ($pipes[0]);
    while (!feof ($pipes[1])) {
            // I have tried with the following uncommented as well
            // That led to the while loop exiting prematurely for some reason...
        // stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], false);
        $output = fread ($pipes[1], 4096);
        // stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], true);

        file_put_contents ('/tmp/dpcp-tool-' . time (), $output);
        fwrite ($pipes[0], 'a');
        fflush ($pipes[0]);
        file_put_contents ('/tmp/publishOutcome-' . time (), $reply);
        sleep(5);
    }

    file_put_contents('/tmp/died-' . time(), $entered);
    fclose ($pipes[0]);
    fclose ($pipes[1]);
    $return_value = proc_close ($process);
}
```